# PHP is Missing mysql pdo Driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, symfony, php-7

I'm trying to run a Symfony 3 app with php 7 installed from source and I'm getting a Missing PDO driver exception.  According to http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_MYSQL the PDO_MYSQL extension is now part of PHP core.

Q1.a) If I have the PDO_MYSQL extension (which I must, since its core)  does that mean that I also have the mysql pdo driver?

Q2.b) Is there further runtime configuration I have to do to make sure that the driver gets used?

I've tried adding

extension=php_pdo.so

extension=php_pdo_mysql.so

to my loaded php.ini file.

Q2.a) Are these the correct extension names?  How could I find out?
Q2.b)Do I even have to provide extension references for core php elements?

Finally:

Q3. How can I check whether my PHP install included the mysql pdo driver and how do I make sure that it is being loaded at runtime?

Thanks for your input.

Edit 1: I'm running on Linux Mint.
Edit 2: Here are a couple more details on what I'm seeing on my end:

"On starting up the built in php server I get the following message:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0"

This message suggests to me that either the extension references are incorrect or the extension does not exist.  I used "dpkg -L php-mysql" and found that the package was installed in "/usr/share/doc/php-mysql" however, when I check in the php-mysql directory, all I see is a changelog and a copyright file (with hiddens shown).  Is this the true install location of the package and, if so, should there be more in this directory?

Comment: Depending on the packager `pdo_mysql` might be an extra package. Like it's the case of dotdeb's jessie packages.

Comment: Look into `phpinfo` and look for PDO MySQL. `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: What does `php -m` or `php -i | grep PDO` say?

Comment: I forgot to mention, phpinfo() only shows the sqlite pdo driver as being enabled.  I suspect this is because either a) the driver isn't enabled correctly in php.ini or b) it is not installed.  How can I tell which of these is the case?

Comment: php -m:  [PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter  php -i | grep PDO: PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled

Comment: dpkg should be listing a lot more directories than just the documentation... for example, when I run that command I get `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so` among others... `/usr/share/doc/php5-mysql` is just the last one in the list

Answer (score 5):

.so implies you are on Linux - did you install PHP as a package. You probably need to install the pdo/mysql package - PHP libraries may be "core", but not necessarily in the main package (confusing, but it just means it's not PEAR delivered, really).

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Or, if you're running PHP7:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

This should restart the apache automatically, but to be sure you could do:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The package installer for php-mysql should have put the .so libraries in `/usr/lib/php/yyyymmdd/` - if you had installed PHP as a package, it would be looking here.

However, since you installed from source, it seems that PHP is looking elsewhere for the libraries. You can create symlinks from `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/` to the package installed libraries.

Comment: This is one of the solutions I tried before posting this question.  I've tried it again to no effect.  Is there something I need to do after installing this package to get it to work? dpkg command says that its successfully installed.

Comment: @allen You'll need to restart the webserver. If apache 2.4 on ubuntu, `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Hi @JeffPuckettII.  Good thought, but I've already done this.  I'll be posting some more info on the main post shortly that will hopefully narrow down the list of possible causes.

Comment: hmm - sorry, I missed where you said you'd installed PHP7 from source... I can only assume that this means PHP is installed with different paths to what the normal package system does... is there a reason you haven't installed PHP7 as a package?

Comment: There wasn't much package support for php7 when I installed it, I know there are some now.  How would I go about switching from my install from source to a package based install?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If possible, I'd take a snapshot of the server, then remove the source installed PHP and then follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: You were right, the issue was fixed by wiping php7 from my machine and reinstalling via package.  Thanks again for your help.